# how do I determine the user role after publishing the site?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i'm making a website that has two different types of users, admins and normal users, I have read a lot about how to create different pages based on type of user by PHP and SQl, and I noticed that most of them determine the role of the user through the database (field called type, role etc.) after user created an account.

so my question is how do I determine the user type/role if i publish the site? Do I have to go back every time to the database to specify the type/role of user every time a new user logs up!?

Comment: role would be kept in a session after login, i think thats what you are asking

Comment: Are you storing your admjn

Comment: @ThalindaBandara I did not understand what you mean, but there are several administrators and they create their accounts in a normal way like users, which their information storing in DB

Comment: @tim yeah i know about the session and how to make the Login page redirects based on user role, but how determine their role in the first place?

Comment: well you already have to check the db when they login, so use that query to pull out the role also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your storing them both in same table then you have to sign in every user as a normal user after signing you can decide what type of user is this and give them the appropriate user level that's more secured that's mean you have to create a another admin pannel from there you can chage user level and new users So you don't have to acce phpmyadmin pannel. The problem is i can't understand how you are deciding wich is wich if there is a method to choos then i suggests you to write a algorithm to choos admin and normal user programmitacly  that way it's easy.

Ok now i think i got it.  We should decide what type of user is this when they create account as example when they create account you can ask a question like how many years of expireance do they have so let's say they have more than 4 yeaes of expireance then that's a administration account if there expireance is less than 4 years then that's a normal account.  Just don't let the user to know how you are deciding the account type.  any way i think making a seperate super admin pannel to your self is better because that way only you can decide wich is wich

```
Userid  |  usertype    |       usernam
  1         |        1            |         jhone
  2         |        2            |         mark
```

User type 1  = admin
user type 2 =  normal user

Table structure that you should use

And every time they login you querying db and storing info in session in your situation $_session['userid']  And $_session['role/type']

Comment: what is "create a another admin pannel"? is making a page on the website that control and manage the DB without access it directly or what?

Comment: and yeah the admins and users in the same table, but if i made different forms that maybe lead the normal user to access to admin's form

Comment: Create a another admin pannel mean is only you can access that admin pannel from that admin pannel you can remove users block user and much more only you can access that admin pannel.  So let's say new user is registered then that user is showed up in your admin pannel then you can decide what type of user is this and from there you can update the table this same thing liks phpmyadmin but more user friendly

Comment: this way you don't have to access cpanell every time new user appear you can just create a dropdown with user levels and select user level from there then click button.  And another important thing you should password protect you super admin pannel(your admin pannel) using. Htaccess

Comment: I think I understood it, it depends on some information provided by the user, on my case there is no info that specifies the type of user but maybe i can give the admins a secret code